# Python Requests: Trying to post data

Tags: python, charles-proxy

I'm using Charles to debugg a web application and reverse engineer it.

When I look at a request from my browser, I'm able to use Charles to see what the body content should look like:

```
{
"projectIds": [1016190671],
"statusId": 11144371
}
```

When I try:

```
data = {"projectIds": [1016190671], "statusId": 11144371}
client.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Charles says it is being passed like this:

```
projectIds=1016190671&statusId=11144371
```

Are they the same thing? My post is failing and I **think** this is why but I'm not 100% sure. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to

1. Add `'Content-type': 'application/json'` to your headers
2. dump the data with `json.dumps`

If you are trying to post JSON

Comment: That helped. Now I'm getting an internal server error. When I do it from the web browser, it works. However, Python seems to keep breaking. Any thoughts on what I should look for? Or what data should I post to make it easier to understand what is going on?